# Переход в UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Помогите, пожалуйста. Написал приложение с `UINavigationController`. При нажатии на кнопку не работает переход на другую страницу. Я понимаю, что мало информации даю о проблеме. Но вроде все настроил. У меня `Xcode 3.2.5.` Пользовался книгой "Разработка приложений для `iphone ipad` и `ipod touch` с использованием `ios sdk`",глава 9. Кстати, очень хорошая всем рекомендую. Все сделал как надо. Сто раз проверил.

**UPD:**

```
DisclosureButtonController *disclosureButtonController= [[DisclosureButtonController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
disclosureButtonController.title=@"Название"; 
disclosureButtonController.rowImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosureButtonControllerIcon.png"]; 
[array addObject:disclosureButtonController]; 
[disclosureButtonController release];
```

Comment: Приведите код нажатия на кнопку, будет понятнее.

Comment: не вижу у вас в коде использования навигейшн вообще, по идее должно быть что-то типа [self.navigationController pushViewController:disclosureButtonController animated:YES]; перед релизом. Кроме того совершенно не ясно, что за array. Код лучше в вопрос вставьте, очень трудно его в комментарии понять

Comment: Ну вы просили только код кнопки...Тот код который вы привели написан в классе

Comment: так это и есть переход на другую страницу который у вас не работает. Класс большой? Можете его целиком привести?

Comment: @Sergey4590, привет.   
> написан в классе  
  
Честно говоря, непонятно, *где именно* он написан. Логично ведь, что код перехода должен быть в методе (aka функции) кнопки?

Comment: Вас просили код НАЖАТИЯ на кнопку.  А вообще судя по тому коду, что вы показали, то у вас ни одно действие к этой кнопке не привязано. Используйте addTarget:action:forControlEvents: , чтобы привязать действие. PS И что к книжке не шел исходный код глав?

Comment: Так у него код не генерации кнопки вовсе приведен, это явно какой-то потомок UITAbleViewController'а

Comment: @Tuggen, @aknew вы не знаете, а разве принято делать контроллеры для *кнопок* (`DisclosureButtonController`)?

Comment: @Violet , так и я про то же, не кнопка это. Почему-то больше комментить не могу, наверное, ограничение стоит

Comment: Часть текста класса:

    if(childController==nil)
 {
  childController=[[DisclosureDetailController alloc]
       initWithNibName:@"DisclosureDetail" bundle:nil];}
 childController.title=@"Disclosure Button Pressed";
 NSUInteger row=[indexPath row];
 NSString *selectedMovie=[list objectAtIndex:row];
 NSString *detailMessage=[[NSString alloc]
        initWithFormat: @"You pressed 213 %@.",selectedMovie];
 childController.message=detailMessage;
 childController.title=selectedMovie;
 [detailMessage release];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос и поместится, так же невозможно читать

Comment: @Violet, ну судя по всему этот класс пользовательский. А там уж поди разбери кто как его назовет. Поэтому не факт, что это контроллер. Но и не факт, что кнопка. 
Это надо код смотреть..

Comment: @Sergey4590, залейте проект на github и дайте ссылку.

Comment: Таки да, в той книжке этот DisclosureButtonController наследован от чего-то, что в свою очередь наследуются от UITAbleViewController.. Странные названия классов. Раз это котроллер, то зачем в названии упоминать батн?

Comment: В книжке вашей как-то слишком замудрено сделано, почитайте про `UINavigationController` тут - http://www.imaladec.net/story/uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Покажите лучше код класса AppDelegate.m, возможно там не добавлен navigationController

Comment: Добавлен,точно знаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть я чего то не догоняю, но всю дорогу было так

```
-(void)method  
{  
ViewController1 *v1Class = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];  
v1Class.navigationItem.title = @"Detail view";  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:v1Class animated:YES];  
[v1Class release];  
}
```

UPD: В методе -(void)viewdidload{} следует прописать

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(method)];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
[anotherButton release];
```

UPD2: в     AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}

UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;

//self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Вы будете четвертым, кто это автору топика вдолбить пытается :)

Comment: Мде, пора уже написать книжку, курс Objective-c для молодого программиста.

Comment: Вы вот эту ссылку читали? - http://www.imaladec.net/story/uinavigationcontroller

Хватит уже ждать, что вам поднесут все на блюдце с голубой каемочкой. Включайте соображалку и вперед в гугл.

Comment: Я пересмотрел уже ссылок 20. Везде разный код и замудренный нигде нет simple manual где бы просто показывалось как создать и как работает UINavigatinController.

Comment: Вам ответ наверху написали по ссылям ходить даже не надо! У всех зарплата разная, примернуюю статистику можно посмотреть в одном из топиков на сайте Habrahabr.

Comment: @Sergey4590, если вы не можете понять материал, который разжеван до самого простого и в котором куча скриншотов, то, извините, вам лучше не заниматься программированием. Не мучайте себя и занимайтесь тем, что получается.

Comment: @Sergey4590  
> Хватит уже ссылки кидать!  
  
Бывает так, что по ссылкам можно найти полезную информацию.  
  
> Если бы я там все понимал,я бы тут не сидел  
  
Так объясните, *что именно* вы там не понимаете. Мы ведь правда хотим вам помочь, но поймите сами, что "у меня ничего не получается, помогите" - не очень хорошая формулировка для вопроса.

Comment: Жаль...А я думал из меня получится хороший прогер...Можно мне хоть иногда заходить в Xcode?

Comment: VioLet,вы правы на все 100%. Проблема в том,что ссылки которые вы даете,они правильные, и книга по которой я писал приложение тоже очень хорошая,у меня все запускается без ошибок,но переход по кнопке не работает.Я даже несколько раз проект создавал по книге.Хз только почему не работает.Когда нажимаю на кнопку из приложения выкидывает.

Comment: Выкидывает при нажатии на кнопку ... а что пишет в консоле???

Comment: Ничего,просто выкидывает

Comment: Не дает не какой ошибки??? А вы попробовали ответ, который описан выше???

Comment: @x86-64, Наверняка там используется ранее релизнутый объект.
@Sergey4590, ну выложите вы уже один раз код кнопки и код обработки нажатия на нее! (В первом посте не кнопка описана.) Мы не умеем гадать на кофейной гуще, чтобы узнать, почему у вас крэшится приложение.